# Download file with HTTP or HTTPS in Node

Tags: node.js, file, http, https, download

I know how to download a file with the `http` library and with the `https` library.

But what do I do if I want to give the user the option to do both?

Currently I have code that looks like this

```
var downloadFile = function (url) {
  var protocol = url.replace(/^(.*?):.*/, '$1');
  var protocolLibrary = require(protocol);
  protocolLibrary.get(url, function (response) { ... });
};
```

Is that the best way to do this?

Comment: So, what is the big question here?  You seem to already know that you use either `http.get()` or `https.get()` depending upon what the user wants.  What else do you need help with?

Comment: Yeah it's server side. I have a simple form on the client that the user enters a URL into. When the form is submitted, `downloadFile(url)` is called.

Comment: So, what's the question?  Look in the url and call either `http.get()` or `https.get()` like you're already attempting to do.

Comment: Is this a best practice? It seems hacky to me to require the library dynamically. Will requiring the library dynamically add tons of extra time to the call?

Comment: OK, I added an answer that selects the appropriate protocol library in a safer way.

Answer (score 0):

The way you were doing left open a gigantic security hole where the end-user could cause almost any existing node module on your server to be run (if they knew the path to it or it was already in the `require()` search path).

You can limit the libraries selectable to a preloaded few like this:

```
var urlParser = require('url');

var supportedLibraries = {
    "http:": require('http'),
    "https:": require('https')
};

function downloadFile(url) {
    var parsed = urlParser.parse(url);
    var lib = supportedLibraries[parsed.protocol || "http:"];
    if (lib) {
        lib.get(url, function (response) { ... });
    } else {
        // error for invalid protocol
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm not trying to serve files. I'm downloading them. Updating the question now

Comment: I'm not downloading a file for a client. I need the server to download it and then upload it to S3

Comment: @merlinpatt - Does my current solution work as an answer to your issue?  If so, please mark this (or some other answer) as your selected answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of the answer and this will indicate to the community that your question has been answered and will earn you some reputation points that can earn you more privileges here over time.